# Installing software on a new computer, issue relating to Java

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have installed IntelliJ on new a machine. Installation went OK. When I started to test projects, very simple (hello world type) projects for JavaFX and Android  (Java and Kotlin) do not work. I am using IntelliJ Ultimate Edition, Build #IU-191.7141.44 built on May 7, 2019
java version is "12.0.1" 2019-04-16.
Java2SE programs work from IntelliJ and Eclipse.

For JavaFX On IntelliJ, I get an error, cannot resolve symbol javafx from all javafx imports. 
import javafx.application.Application;

For Android Programs, issue is with Gradle. I also installed gradle-5.4.1-bin and put it in the path environment variable. Did not solve the problem.
I would appreciate very much if someone can help me with these problems.

Comment: Older versions of Java included JavaFX in the JVM.  As of Java 9+, that is longer the case.  Java 9+ requires you to get JavaFX as a module. You need to download the appropriate [JavaFX runtime](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).

Are you making a modular or non-modular JavaFX project? If [these instructions](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) help I can move them to an answer.

Comment: I am creating non-modular projects. You are right about JDK 12 not including JavaFX support. I downloaded JDK 11.2, and it did not work either. On a different machine, I have JDK 11.1 and it works, but I couldn't find download for JDK 11.1.